# Move caption in on attachment page

Tags: attachments, captions

I am looking for a way to edit the way Wordpress’ native gallery displays images when clicked on. Specifically, I need to move the title below the image.

A more detailed explanation:
I setup a gallery using the built-in gallery inside of vanilla wordpress 3.6. It displays correctly and when I click on an image, I am directed to that image's page. I need to know where can I edit this particular page? I need to move the title to the bottom as well as some other stuff.

Comment: `attachment.php` is the file that loads a "single" attachment.

Comment: @GhostToast I don't think that's what I'm looking for. When you click on an image from the gallery, it takes you to a page with only that one image on it. I need to edit that page

Comment: There is a setting in the Gallery to link to the Media File or the Attachment Page. If you go straight to Media File, it is just the image. The Attachment Page is `attachment.php`

Comment: @GhostToast I found the attachment.php, it was in my current theme. Not sure how that works, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In a theme `image.php` is the template that displays a single image attachment. There are many similar templates for other attachment types. The Codex has more information about [attachment display templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Attachment_display).

If you don't have an `image.php` template you can quickly make one by making a copy of `single.php` and renaming it. Then you can edit it to your liking.